# JRViewer is not getting visible on the intended frame although have initialized and added to the frame

Tags: java, swing, jasper-reports

On click event of a button on one frame I have written this code

```
JasperPrint jasperPrint = new business_logics.Client().generateReport(this);
Report report = new Report(jasperPrint);
```

and the core code is like this

```
public JasperPrint generateReport(Component o) {
    try {
        JasperPrint jasperPrint = null;
        if (hm == null) {
            hm = new HashMap();
        }

        try {
           String source="Client.jasper";
           jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(source, hm, new ConnectionSeeker().giveConnection(o));
        } catch (JRException e) {
           System.err.println(""+e.getMessage());
        }
        return jasperPrint;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.err.println(""+ex);
        return null;
    }
}
```

and the frame on which I want to show the JRViewer is this:

```
public class Report extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    private JRViewer viewer;

    public Report(JasperPrint  j) {
       initComponents();
       viewer = new JRViewer(j);
       add(viewer);
       pack();
       this.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Even if I don't like the code style, its nothing  wrong in what you have posted, please show your initComponents() method. (if you remove this it will work)....

Comment: it worked. thanks but  and surely i ll be careful while posting from next time about framing the question :)